# Tensorflow py3.5 install from source: "not a supported wheel"?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, tensorflow

Previously I've installed tensorflow from source on Ubuntu 16.04 for Python 2.7, and it worked fine.

For Python 3.5 (I made a new anaconda environment), I'd installed one of the binary versions, but I was getting warning messages..

**EDIT, using the downloaded binary wheel, the messages I get are...**

```
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:910] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
```

**...and the code seems to run significantly slower than if I run using my native-compiled py27.**

So, I uninstalled the "old" tensorflow binary (for py35), and went through the instructions at [the Tensorflow Install from Sources page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources), installed all the packages, ran the ./configure, pointed it to the right version of python (~/anaconda2/envs/py35/bin/python, and its corresponding library paths), chose my CUDA options, got all the way down to the end with no errors in the build...

And at the final step it tells me it's "not a supported wheel on this platform" -- you mean the platform I just built on?

```
$ ./configure
...
$ bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package 
...
$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
Thu Mar 9 23:17:35 CST 2017 : === Using tmpdir: /tmp/tmp.RrsUxPKxFg
~/tmp/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package.runfiles ~/tmp/tensorflow
~/tmp/tensorflow
/tmp/tmp.RrsUxPKxFg ~/tmp/tensorflow
Thu Mar 9 23:17:36 CST 2017 : === Building wheel
~/tmp/tensorflow
Thu Mar 9 23:17:45 CST 2017 : === Output wheel file is in: /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
$ sudo -H pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl 
tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Here are a few checks...

```
$ python --version
Python 3.5.3 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
$ which python
/home/myusername/anaconda2/envs/py35/bin/python
$ which pip
/home/myusername/anaconda2/envs/py35/bin/pip
$ pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /home/myusername/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages
$
```

Can anyone offer a suggestion?

I've seen various posts about problems re. "not a supported wheel" where people are using downloaded binary wheels that don't match the right version of python (e.g. cp34 vs cp35), and posts about installing from source on Windows, but haven't seen posts like mine: involving installing from source, correct "matching" versions of Python, on Linux. Checked the Github issues for tensorflow, didn't see this there either.

Comment: Thanks for reading my post. I edited to emphasize why I want to do this.  And install instructions actually have a whole section on "Installing with Anaconda", with no mention of "not even officially supported": https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#installing_with_anaconda

Comment: When you do `sudo -H pip install ...`, are you sure that you're running the same `pip` as reported by `which pip`? It looks like Anaconda is setting a virtualenv, and `sudo` doesn't preserve `$PATH`, so it's possible that `sudo -H pip install` is using a different version of `pip` (e.g. for Python 2).

Comment: Dohhhp.  @mrry that's it. Make your comment an answer and you get the vote!    "$ sudo -H which pip" gives "/usr/local/bin/pip".  So "sudo -H ~/anaconda2/envs/py35/bin/pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl "  fixes everything.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error caused by running `sudo -H pip install ...` to install the compiled PIP package. Anaconda uses a virtual environment, which overrides the path to the `pip` executable. However, the `sudo` command [does not preserve the user's `$PATH` environment variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83191/220140), so `sudo -H pip install ...` will use the system-installed `pip`, which in this case corresponds to a different version of Python.

Fortunately, if you are using Anaconda, you do not need to use `sudo` to run `pip`, because the entire environment is stored in a directory that your user owns.